# Perform operation on child browser in uft

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

I've tested many ways to get this going but had no luck. Firstly, thank you for reviving my post & supplying your suggestions.

I am writing a script that click on a Add image(+) on IE 8 & opens a new browser with some web elements on it. Upon querying object spy, Interestingly the child browser has weird lengthy title as URL, the page has blank title as below

```
`"Class Name:=Browser",
"abs_x:=203",
"abs_y:=95",
"application version:=internet explorer 8",
"hasmenubar:=False",
"hasstatusbar:=True",
"hastoolbar:=True",
"height:=626",
"hwnd:=8651952",
"name:=",
"number of tabs:=1",
"opentitle:=",
"openurl:=http://10\.207\.182\.123:8888/index\.php\?module=Products&action=Popup&html=Popup_picker&form=HelpDeskEditView&popuptype=specific&fromlink=",
"title:=http://10\.207\.182\.123:8888/index\.php\?module=Products&action=Popup&html=Popup_picker&form=HelpDeskEditView&popuptype=specific&fromlink=",
"top_level_hwnd:=5440308",
"version:=internet explorer 8",
"width:=644"`

`"Class Name:=Page",
"abs_x:=203",
"abs_y:=95",
"height:=606",
"hwnd:=4654664",
"name:=test",
"text:=",
"title:=",
"url:=http://10\.207\.182\.123:8888/index\.php\?module=Products&action=Popup&html=Popup_picker&form=HelpDeskEditView&popuptype=specific&fromlink=",
"width:=644"`
```

My script involves working on child browser, searching for a value & selecting it from child webpage. Although when I use `if Browser("creationtime=1").exist then statements ...end if`. The script evaluates the condition but fails to perform any operation.I believe that script is not activating the child browser. I've tried to sync the child browser `browser("creationtime=1").sync. This is also failing. can you please suggest if there are any other approaches to work with it?

Comment: Run a loop and count how many browser are opened, may be there are more than two browsers opened. Which version of QTP/UFT you are using? If you are using UFT, than you can give it a try as [Insight](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/The-Future-of-Testing-Blog/A-guide-to-Image-Based-Testing-with-HP-UFT-s-Insight/ba-p/6355855#.VgF6GdVVhBc) object.

Comment: I am running UFT 12.2. When I record the step, I can see browser name as browser & page name as page. my requirement is to use DP & avoid recording mode. I can confirm that there are only 2 browsers opened.

Comment: Add this line **`Msgbox Browser("title:=.*HelpDeskEditView&popuptype.*").Page("url:=.*HelpDeskEditView&popuptype.*").Exist`** and see what's it's returning.

Comment: I was lately able to handle this using wildcard & ordinal identifier creation time. Thank you for your efforts :)

Comment: Glad you cracked it.